# WSO2 Identity Server Custom Authentication Context Class

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need to add in an additional (or modify a current) Authentication Context Class (the URI) on a SAML2 SSO setup for an Identity Provider (a AuthnContextClassRef). How do I go about this? The IdP I am integrating with needs a custom one to enable different functionality.

I cannot find these in an XML settings or anything and the reference to them in the Jira does not explain how to go around this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. What you have to do is write your own SAML response builder. There you can write your own logic to modify the SAML response. You can find a sample that customizes the default SAML response of Identity Server in [1].

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/12/customizing-saml2-response-and-saml2-assertion-in-wso2/